# Focusing first control in the form using jquery

Tags: jquery

Using jquery how do I focus the first element (edit field, text area, dropdown field, etc)
in the form when the page load?

Something like:

```
document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();
```

but using jquery.

Another requirement, don't focus the first element when the form has class="filter".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For the background I used the script in *ruby on rails* app.
After trying all your answer and found out they all **doesn't works**,
With a search on google i found this snippet that **works**:

```
$(function() {
  $("form:not(.filter) :input:visible:enabled:first").focus();
});
```

It turn out `$('form :input:first')` match the hidden input that *rails* insert on every form.

Comment: This seems to ignore "select" controls.

Answer (score 72):

```
$('form:not(.filter) :input:visible:enabled:first').focus()
```

This will select the first visible input element (`<input />`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`) that doesn't have the class `filter` in it.

Answer (score 13):

I like to mark my chosen element with a class and select by class rather than leaving it up to the order of the elements on the page.  I find this much easier than trying to remember to update my "what's the real first element" algorithm when selecting elements that may or may not be hidden, may or may not be injected by the framework, ...

```
  $(document).ready( function() {
     $('input.js-initial-focus:first').focus(); // choose first just in case
  });
```

Comment: very good tip because I do not want to be dropdown/select-tag focused first, when below a textbox/input comes. Thus I give the textbox a class="initial-focus". Furthermore the jquery solution from Zakaria does not work with an asp.net mvc dropdownlistfor because when the dialog opens there is a validation error: no element selected. But thats not true...

Comment: FWIW - I now prepend classes that are used for behaviors with "js" to distinguish them from classes used for styling.  It's a good practice to not reuse style classes for behaviors and this helps to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a one line solution, but it takes into consideration of the **real** first user input field (may it be <input /> or <select> tag).

You just have to tweak this a bit more and you get what you need.

P.S: I have tested this code works in FireFox, Chrome, and IE6.

```
function focusFirstFormField() {
    try {
        var selector = $("#formid");
        if (selector.length >= 1 && selector[0] && selector[0].elements && selector[0].elements.length > 0) {
            var elements = selector[0].elements;
            var length = elements.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                var elem = elements[i];
                var type = elem.type;

                // ignore images, hidden fields, buttons, and submit-buttons
                if (elem.style.display != "none" /* check for visible */ && type != "image" && type != "hidden" && type != "button" && type != "submit") {
                    elem.focus();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(err) { /* ignore error if any */ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("form").find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with jQuery dialogs which were invisible on the page but were still selected by the selector:

```
$(":text:visible:enabled:first").focus();
```

After alot of playing around I finally came up with a solution that excluded all inputs in divs with a class of .dialog by adding a ".not() on the end. This may be useful to somebody else.
This is my selector:

```
$(":text:visible:enabled:first").not("div .dialog input").focus();
```